# Cloning datepicker

Tags: jquery, dom, datepicker

Well, I know there is a lots of posts about it, but I have tried many solutions so far, but couldn't make it work. What happens is that when I clone the div, the fields that are cloned with datepicker changes simultaneously, so, dosen't matter what date i select in one field will be on the other too.
what am i missing, so i can reset the values to new ones?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {

$( '.datepicker').datepicker('destroy'); 

var num = $('.clonedInput').length; 
var newNum = new Number(num + 1);   
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

newElem.find('#label_val_ini label').attr('for', 'val_ini' + newNum);
newElem.find('#input_val_ini input').attr('class', 'calendario' + newNum).attr('name', 'val_ini[]' + newNum).val('');
newElem.find('#input_val_ini input').attr('class', 'calendario' + newNum).attr('class', 'calendario' + newNum).val('');


newElem.find('#label_val_fim label').attr('for', 'val_fim' + newNum);
newElem.find('#input_val_fim input').attr('class', 'calendario' + newNum).attr('name', 'val_fim[]' + newNum).val('');
newElem.find('#input_val_fim input').attr('class', 'calendario' + newNum).attr('class', 'calendario' + newNum).val(''); 
$('#input' + num).after(newElem);
$('#btnDel').attr('disabled',false);
if (newNum == 50)
$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled',true);
$( '.datepicker').datepicker();
});
$('#btnDel').click(function() {
var num = $('.clonedInput').length; 
$('#input' + num).remove();     
$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled',false);
if (num-1 == 1)
$('#btnDel').attr('disabled',true);
});
$('#btnDel').attr('disabled',true);
});

<form action="inclui_pacote.php" method="post" id="sign-up_area">
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
<table>
 <tr>
<td width="90"><label for="val_ini">Início de validade:</label></td>
<td width="144"><input name="val_ini[]" type="text" class="datepicker" tabindex="1" value=""   size="10" maxlength="10" id="input_val_ini"/></td>

<td width="90"><label for="val_fim">Fim da validade:</label></td>
<td width="144"><input name="val_fim[]" type="text" class="datepicker" tabindex="1" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" id="input_val_fim"/></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
  <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+ Hotel" />
  <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="- Hotel"/>
  <input name="cadastrar" type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to clone the datePicker?

Creating the other datePicker from the start, hiding it if needed, and changing its value when the value of the first datePicker is changed wouldn't do the job?

The thing is that the datePicker is not anymore a single DOM object once the plugin has been applied. So cloning the original DOM element, even with all its datePicker data won't create an object alike.

Another solution would be instead of cloning the original datePicker, to create a new INPUT element, applying datePicker on it, then again giving it the value of the first DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery creates both a class **and** an ID, and both get cloned; neither should be there in the clone.

```
    $('.calendar:last').removeClass('hasDatepicker').attr('id',"").datepicker();
```

I hope this works for you like it did for me.